# Isset get page with php correct usage

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm calling my pages on 'index.php' via 'incude' statements. I've had to use 'isset' to get them to work but the 'yourtweets.php' does not load when I click the link in my navbar. Am I using it correctly?

Link code;

```
 <a href="?page=yourtweets" class="nav-link">Your Tweets</a>
```

index.php code;

```
<?php
      include("functions.php");
      include("views/header.php");

      if (isset($_GET['page']) == 'timeline') {
          include("views/timeline.php");

        } else if (isset($_GET['page']) == 'yourtweets') {

            include("views/yourtweets.php");

      } else {
        include("views/home.php");
      }
    ?>
```

Comment: `isset()` returns a boolean value, not a string.  You can't compare isset() == "a string". Try `if (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == 'yourtweets')`

Comment: @EatPeanutButter That worked if I used it for all my menu items. ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php):

> Returns TRUE if var exists and has value other than NULL. FALSE otherwise.

You are checking whether a boolean (TRUE/FALSE) is equal to the name of your pages. Replace it with the following and it should work:

```
if (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == 'timeline') { //if page is set and page = timeline
      include("views/timeline.php");

    } else if (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == 'yourtweets') {

        include("views/yourtweets.php");

  } else {
    include("views/home.php");
  }
```

Hope this helps!

Edit: Sorry @EatPeanutButter, only saw your comment after I posted my answer!